# Django - Models category error in Admin: “Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices”

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

So I am trying to build a recipe field in django-admin. I have a Model category called `Meals` and I have categories to chose from on the admin page but as soon as I try to save my entry, I get the `Select a valid choice. Breakfast is not one of the available choices` & prevents me from saving anything.

I've tried moving the `daily_meals` value from Recipe Field into Meal Category and uncommenting the first `meal` and commenting the second value in Recipe Field.

How do I create new meals in the meals category, just like the food category, while already having pre-saved meals in the list?

[Meal categories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQ6zU.png)

[admin error after save](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yS3bT.png)

Here is my code:

## Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils import timezone




# Food Category
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=True)


    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

# Meal Category
class Meal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=True)



    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'meal'
        verbose_name_plural = 'meals'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


# Recipe Field
class Recipe(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    daily_meals = (
        ('Breakfast','Breakfast'),
        ('Brunch','Brunch'),
        ('Elevenses','Elevenses'),
        ('Lunch','Lunch'),
        ('Tea','Tea'),
        ('Supper','Supper'),
        ('Dinner','Dinner'),
    )
    # meal = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices = daily_meals)
    meal = models.ForeignKey(Meal, choices = daily_meals, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    ingredients = models.TextField(blank=True)
    directions = models.TextField(blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

## Admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Recipe, Category, Meal



class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'slug')
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('name',)}


admin.site.register(Category, CategoryAdmin)




class MealAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'slug')
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('name',)}


admin.site.register(Meal, MealAdmin)





class RecipeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('created',)

admin.site.register(Recipe, RecipeAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ForeignKey fields do not typically use choices. The choices are generated from what is in the database. If you construct choices yourself, `choice[0]` must be a valid primary key of the `Meal` table. That being said, you can use the [`limit_choices_to`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to) parameter if you want restrict the choices to certain instances:

```
daily_meals = ['Breakfast', 'Brunch', 'Elevenses', 'Lunch', 'Tea', 'Supper', 'Dinner']
# ...
meal = models.ForeignKey(Meal, limit_choices_to={'name__in': daily_meals}, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
```